# UVa Live 6823 Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

How does the following code work for the problem [Uva Live 6823](http://icpcarchive.ecs.baylor.edu/index.php?option=onlinejudge&Itemid=99999999&page=show_problem&category=&problem=4835&mosmsg=Submission%20received%20with%20ID%202144197)?
I just want an explanation for the algorithm used in this code.
Thanks in advance.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string st;
    while(cin>> st){
        long long int cnt=0,x=0,arr[]={1,0,0};
        for(int a=0;a<st.length();a++){
            if(!isdigit(st[a])){
                x=0;
                arr[0]=1;
                arr[1]=arr[2]=0;
            }
            else{
                x=(x+st[a]-48)%3;
                cnt+=arr[x];
                arr[x]++;
            }
        }
        cout<< cnt <<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This algorithm makes use of the [divisibility by 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule#Divisibility_by_3_or_9) rule, namely, if the sum of the digits of a number are divisible by 3, then the number is divisible by 3. It keeps track of the frequency of occurrence for the remainder of the sum of the digits, divided by 3 (eg. 0, 1 or 2). Anytime a new digit is added, the substrings with the same remainder adds another permutation substring that is divisible by 3. Note: the constant used `48` refers to the ASCII value for `'0'`.

This is probably best illustrated by example. Consider the string `12321`, being processed digit by digit.

```
// "iteration" #0 (st[a] = '')
x = 0
arr[] = {1,0,0}
cnt = 0
// iteration #1 (st[a]='1'). '1' is not divisible by three.
x = 1
arr[] = {1,1,0}
cnt   = 0
// iteration #2 (st[a]='2'). '12' is divisible by three.
x = 0
arr[] = {2,1,0}
cnt   = 1
// iteration #3 (st[a]='3'). '123' and '3' are divisible by three
x = 0
arr[] = {3,1,0}
cnt   = 3
// iteration #4 (st[a]='2'). No new divisible by three substrings
x = 2
arr[] = {3,1,1}
cnt   = 3
// iteration #5 (st[a]='1'). '12321', '321' and '21' are divisible by 3.
// note, the other times when x = 0, st[0..a] = '', '12', '123'
x = 0
arr[] = {4,1,1}
cnt   = 6
```

You could continue adding digits, and see how it works. When it hits a non-digit character, the counting resets, because any non-digit character cannot participate in a permutation.